# Grid of prices and quantities in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

**Context**

I'd like to visually explain the dynamic of prices.

- People willing to sell at a certain price, a certain quantity, the offers
- People willing to pay a certain price for a certain quantity, the bids

When Bids cross(=) offers, it trades.

Using chain to show a chain of prices made initially sense but despite my reading of the chapter on chain I am still puzzled by this library.

So I decided to go back to basic node definition as below.
The result does partially the job (it shows a grids of prices) but once playing with my code, I have a problem of scaling cause nodes are defined in absolute.
When prices are described as 100, my positioning is OK.
But obviously, when prices are lower, I have a scaling effect and all the nodes are almost superposed.

**My question**

I need to improve the scalability of my diagram.

**How should it work ?**

The price boundaries are determined by 4 inputs

1. `\bid`
2. `\offer`
3. `\Nprices`
4. `\tick`

and

- `\Ubound = \offer + (\Nprices - 1)* \tick`
- `\Lbound = \bid   - (\Nprices - 1)* \tick`

I used an Excel spreadsheet since I 'd like to have the same rendering .

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Example 1**

[image]

leads to

[image]

The central column (main chain ?) of prices is defined by `\Ubound`, `\Lbound`.
The chain of bids starts at `\bid` and goes below on the left hand side
The chain of offers starts at `\offer` and  goes above on the right hand side.
The gray area on the main chain corresponds to the possible prices available between `\bid` and `\offer`.

**Example 2**

`\tick` is now 0.5, I get more granularity between prices.

[image]

[image]

**Example 3**

`\bid=\offer`

[image]

[image]

I get the following result so far
[image]
[image]

*Rendering is OKish*

[image]

*Rendering is not OK*

[image]

*Rendering is not OK*

[image]

using manually `yscale=5` with

```
%My variables
\def\bid{10}            %Bid price          % 99 euros but any stock price
\def\offer{10}          %Offer price        % 101 euros but any stock price 
\def\Qbid{50}           %Bid Quantity       % random numbers, not essential,
\def\Qoffer{50}         %Offer Quantity     % random numbers, not essential 
\def\tick{0.1}          %Tick for prices    % tick between 2 prices, = 0.10,0.25,0.50,1, 5, 10...
\def\Nprices{3}         % number of bids or offers in the chain of prices and quantities
```

[image]

**Where do I need help ?**

1. Do I need to switch to chain (sigh) to solve the scalability issue ?
2. Thanks to schrodinger'scat I have a (still very) manual solution for prices that are integers. However if prices are not, I get a problem for loops.
3. I'd like to highlight the best bid (the highest one) and best offer (the lowest one) and set others to `color=gray`.
4. The next step of the graph will consist in showing the idea of convergence towards bid = offer and probably get a nice animation at the end.
5. Am of course open to any suggestion improving the readability.

   ```
   \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
   \usetikzlibrary {chains,scopes,fit,backgrounds}
   \usepackage{eurosym}
   \begin{document}

   %I define the conditions of what I want to highlight
   \newif\ifShowBid        \ShowBidtrue
   \newif\ifShowOffer      \ShowOffertrue
   \newif\ifShowSpread     \ShowSpreadtrue

   %My variables
   \def\bid{100}           %Bid price          % 99 euros but any stock price
   \def\offer{100}         %Offer price        % 101 euros but any stock price 
   \def\Qbid{50}           %Bid Quantity       % random numbers, not essential,
   \def\Qoffer{50}         %Offer Quantity     % random numbers, not essential 
   \def\tick{1}            %Tick for prices    % tick between 2 prices, = 0.10,0.25,0.50,1, 5, 10...
   \def\Nprices{3}         % number of bids or offers in the chain of prices and quantities

   \tikzset{
   Pbid/.style={
       rounded corners,draw=blue,fill=blue!20,text=blue,text width = 3em,align=center},
   Poffer/.style={
       Pbid,draw=red,fill=red!20,text=red!70},
   Qbid/.style={
       rectangle,fill=blue!20,draw=none,text=blue,text width = 2em,align=center},
   Qoffer/.style={
       Qbid,text=red,fill=red!20},
   PriceDiscovery/.style={, fill= gray, ultra thick, rounded corners,opacity=0.5,draw=red, line width =3 pt},
   }

   \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2mm and 0.3cm]

   \foreach 
       [evaluate={
               \Nbid   = \bid - \i* \tick;                 %  list of bids
               \Noffer = \offer + \i* \tick;               %  list of offers
               \Qbid   = int(\Qbid - 10 *\i* rand);        %  list of Qbids
               \Qoffer = int(\Qoffer - 10 *\i* rand);      %  list of Qoffers      
               }] \i in {0,...,\Nprices}
   {
       \node[Pbid]                 (bid-\i)    at (0,\Nbid)    {\euro{\Nbid}};
       \node[Poffer]               (offer-\i)  at (1.5,\Noffer)    {\euro{\Noffer}};
       \node[Qbid,left=of bid-\i]  (Qbid-\i)                   {$\times \Qbid$};
       \node[Qoffer,right=of offer-\i] (Qoffer-\i)             {$\times \Qoffer$}; 
   }
   \ifnum \bid=\offer
   \node[fit=(Qbid-0)(Qoffer-0), draw,fill= red!50, rounded corners,opacity=0.5,label=right:{Trading level}] {};
   \ShowBidfalse
   \ShowOfferfalse
   \ShowSpreadfalse
   \fi
   % I need to highlight different parts of the graph
   % 1- the whole set of bids and offers
   \ifShowSpread
       \begin{scope}[on background layer]
       \node[PriceDiscovery, fit=(Qbid-0.south west)(Qoffer-0.north east),label=right:{Best market}] {Price discovery area};
       \end{scope}
   \fi
   % 2- the whole set of offers
   \ifShowOffer
       \begin{scope}[on background layer]
       \node[fit=(Qoffer-0)(offer-\Nprices), fill= red!50, rounded corners,opacity=0.5,label=right:{Offers}] {};
       \end{scope}
   \fi
   % 3- the whole set of bids
   \ifShowBid
       \begin{scope}[on background layer]
       \node[fit=(Qbid-0)(bid-\Nprices), fill= blue!50, rounded corners,opacity=0.5,label=left:{Bids}] {};
       \end{scope}
   \fi
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
   ```

and edited version

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {chains,scopes,fit,backgrounds}
        \usetikzlibrary{calc}
        \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    Pbid/.style={
        rounded corners,draw=blue,fill=blue!20,text=blue,text width = 3em,align=center},
    Poffer/.style={
        Pbid,draw=red,fill=red!20,text=red!70},
    Qbid/.style={
        rectangle,fill=blue!20,draw=none,text=blue,text width = 2em,align=center},
    Qoffer/.style={
        Qbid,text=red,fill=red!20},
    PriceDiscovery/.style={, fill= gray, ultra thick, rounded corners,opacity=0.5,draw=red, line width =3 pt},
}


%I define the conditions of what I want to highlight
\newif\ifShowBid        %\ShowBidtrue
\newif\ifShowOffer      %\ShowOffertrue
\newif\ifShowSpread     \ShowSpreadtrue
\newif\ifShowPGrid      %\ShowPGridtrue

%My variables
\def\bid{25}        % Bid price         % 99 euros but any stock price
\def\offer{25}      % Offer price       % 101 euros but any stock price 
\def\Qbid{50}       % Bid Quantity      % random numbers, not essential,
\def\Qoffer{50}     % Offer Quantity    % random numbers, not essential 
\def\tick{1}        % Tick for prices   % tick between 2 prices, = 0.10,0.25,0.50,1, 5, 10...
\def\Nprices{4}     % number of bids or offers in the chain of prices and quantities

\def\X{1}           % Same column = 0, otherwise symmetry
\def\Y{0.6}         % yscale factor

%I'll use {\LBound,...,\UBound} later, if \tick is not integer, pb with \pgfmathtruncatemacro
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\LBound{\bid   - \Nprices * \tick}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\UBound{\offer + \Nprices * \tick}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\a{\LBound + \tick}
\ifnum \bid=\offer
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\LSpread{\bid}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\USpread{\offer}
\else
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\LSpread{\bid   + \tick}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\USpread{\offer - \tick}
\fi

%% 
%\IfInteger{\tick}
%   \pgfmathsetmacro\LBound{\bid   - \Nprices * \tick}
%   \pgfmathsetmacro\UBound{\offer + \Nprices * \tick}
%   \pgfmathsetmacro\a{\LBound + \tick}
%   
%   \ifnum \bid=\offer
%       \pgfmathsetmacro\LSpread{\bid}
%       \pgfmathsetmacro\USpread{\offer}
%   \else
%       \pgfmathsetmacro\LSpread{\bid   + \tick}
%       \pgfmathsetmacro\USpread{\offer - \tick}
%       \pgfmathsetmacro\b{\LSpread + \tick}
%   \fi


\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=\Y,node distance=10mm and 0.25cm]
            
    % Price axis
    \ifShowPGrid    
    \foreach  \i in {\LBound,...,\UBound}
    \node[gray] (P-\i)  at (-\X-3,\i)   {\euro{\i}};
    \fi 
        
    %   % Prices available in the discovery area
    %   \foreach  \i in {\LSpread,\b,...,\USpread}
    %   \node[gray] (A)     at (0,\i)   {\euro{\i}};
            
        
        
    \foreach 
    [evaluate={
            \Nbid   = \bid - \i* \tick;                 %  list of bids
            \Noffer = \offer + \i* \tick;               %  list of offers
            \Qbid   = int(\Qbid - 10 *\i* rand);        %  list of Qbids
            \Qoffer = int(\Qoffer - 10 *\i* rand);      %  list of Qoffers      
        }] \i in {0,...,\Nprices}
    {
        \node[Pbid]                 (bid-\i)    at (-\X,\Nbid)  {\euro{\Nbid}};
        \node[Poffer]               (offer-\i)  at (\X,\Noffer)     {\euro{\Noffer}};
        \node[Qbid,left=of bid-\i]  (Qbid-\i)                   {$\times \Qbid$};
        \node[Qoffer,right=of offer-\i] (Qoffer-\i)             {$\times \Qoffer$}; 
    }
            
    \ifnum \bid=\offer
        \node[fit=(Qbid-0)(Qoffer-0), draw,fill= red!50, rounded corners,opacity=0.5,label=right:{Trading level}] {};
                        
        \node[star,star points=7,star point ratio=0.4,fill=red,opacity=0.8] at ($(bid-0)!0.5!(offer-0)$) {};
        \ShowBidfalse
        \ShowOfferfalse
        \ShowSpreadfalse
    \else  %%%% I'll do that manually in a poor way but it could be implied from \tick \bid and \offer
                        
        \def\a{\bid+\tick}
        \def\b{\offer-\tick}
                        
                        
    \fi
            
            
    % I need to highlight different parts of the graph
    % 1- the whole set of bids and offers
    \ifShowSpread
    
    \foreach  \i in {\LSpread,...,\USpread}
    \node[gray] (PD-\i)     at (0,\i)   {\euro{\i}};
    
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \node[PriceDiscovery, fit=(bid-0.south west)(offer-0.north east),] {}; %label=right:{Price discovery area}
    \end{scope}
    \fi
    % 2- the whole set of offers
    \ifShowOffer
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \node[fit=(Qoffer-0)(offer-\Nprices), fill= red!50, rounded corners,opacity=0.5,] {}; %label=right:{Offers}
    \end{scope}
    \fi
    % 3- the whole set of bids
    \ifShowBid
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \node[fit=(Qbid-0)(bid-\Nprices), fill= blue!50, rounded corners,opacity=0.5,] {}; %label=left:{Bids}
    \end{scope}
    \fi
            
            
    %Fleches
    %\draw [thick, -latex] (offer-0.west) to [bend left] (offer-1.west);
    %\draw [thick, -latex] (offer-1.west) to [bend left] (offer-2.west);
    %\draw [thick, -latex] (offer-2.west) to [bend left] (offer-3.west);
    %Fleches
    %\draw [thick, -latex] (bid-0.east) to [bend left] (bid-1.east);
    %\draw [thick, -latex] (bid-1.east) to [bend left] (bid-2.east);
    %\draw [thick, -latex] (bid-2.east) to [bend left] (bid-3.east);
            
            
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can always adjust the `yscale` to your needs, e.g. `\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=0.7,node distance=2mm and 0.3cm] ....`. However, you may want to explain what you really want to achieve. It isn't clear to me why you do not just adjust `\tick` to your needs. That is, I do not understand what is meant by "scalability".)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I want to describe the evolution of prices on a stock market. If I owe a share of apple (Marmots love apples no ? ;)  whose price is USD 339.00. If the tick is 0.20 for this share, the price can move 0.20 by 0.20. For other stocks (cheaper ones) like Citigroup worth USD 52.00, the tick will be 0.01. So I need this parameter to describe the grid of prices for each stock.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat So in way, I need the grid of nodes to have a fixed size, but I need its content to follow the rule of the `\tick`. Hence my question about chains.

Comment: Yes, but the question is whether the distance between the nodes should always be the same or depend on the price tags. If the distance between the nodes is to depend on the price tag, is it the distance between the node boundaries or the centers? (`chains` is not good for making the distance vary.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat `chains` is my black cat :)  On the first graph. The "price discovery area" covers one "shadow" (hidden) node that is 100 because `\bid=99`, `\offer = 101` and `\tick=1`. If `\tick=0.5`, the "price discovery area" would have covered three "shadow" (hidden) nodes, 99.50,100,100.50. So to me, the distance between the bid levels or offer levels should be fixed. The price tag should implicitly make sense. (Next step is a hand graph :)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I added an handrawing in edit.

Comment: Thanks for all the edits! However, I have very simple questions: what are the boundary conditions (constant distance between the nodes? etc.), and what is the input?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109329/discussion-between-jet-and-schrodingers-cat).

Comment: I don't know, but this looks more like a table work, maybe a task for `pgfplotstable`. But it is to much for me to check it out, so maybe break it down into single taks in several threads for getting answers.